# Skipping a null array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm deleteing apart of an array and when this method has gone through I get a null point exception. How am I able to make it skip the array with the `null` value?

```
 public static int getTotal(Candidate[] list)   
    {  
        int total = 0;  
        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) 
        {

        total = list[i].getVotes() + total;  
    }

        return total;  
    }
```

Comment: `if(list[i] != null)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
total += list[i] != null ? list[i].getVotes() : 0;
```

In Java 8, your method would be like:

```
public static int getTotal(Candidate[] list) {
    return Stream.of(list)
                 .filter(s -> s != null)
                 .collect(Collectors.summingInt(Candidate::getVotes));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static int getTotal(Candidate[] list)   
 {  
   int total = 0;  
   for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) 
   {
     if (list[i] != null)
     {
       total = list[i].getVotes() + total;  
     }
   }

   return total;  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just protect it with a null check:

```
public static int getTotal(Candidate[] list)   
{
    int total = 0;  

    if (list != null)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) 
        {
            if (list[i] != null)
            {
                total = list[i].getVotes() + total;  
            }
        }
    }

    return total;  
}
```